# How do I change my wallpaper with python using an image from the same directory as the python file?

Tags: python

I wanted for the python script to change my wallpaper from any directory while the .jpg file is in the same directory as the python script, however how do you do it?
I tried things like `'...\\wallpaper.jpg'` or using the os module:

```
import ctypes
import os

current_dir = os.getcwd()
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, 'current_dir\\wallpaper.jpg' , 0)
```

I would like to know If I made any mistakes in the code and a solution to this.

Comment: you can use `wallpaper.jpg` or `\wallpaper.jpg` to access the image

Comment: `current_dir` is variable so use it without `' '` - like `current_dir + "\\wallpaper.jpg"` or use string formatting `"{}\\wallpaper.jpg".format(current_dir)`, or `f-string` like  `f"{current_dir}\\wallpaper.jpg"`. But preferred should be to use `os.path.join(current_dir, "wallpaper.jpg")` and it will add \ automatically. But first check if `getcwd()` really gives folder with code - you could `print()` it. System may run code in different folder (different `Current Working Directory`) and `getcwd()` will get different folder - and safer is to use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`